# wpf multiuser application los Focus on selected Item in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

It's my first project in wpf and my first post here. 
So I have a DataGrid wich takes his data via Linq from SQL Server and keep it actual with SQLNotifications.

These are the Parameters on the DataGrid:

```
 <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" RowHeaderWidth="0" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowHeight="20" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentTickets}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="20" Grid.Row="1" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelektierteZeile, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
```

When someone select any Item it's marked as selected but if any one else open an item with left double click the first User loses the focus.
I save my seletedItem in "SelektierteZeile" and while Debugging i've checked if "SelektierteZeile" turns into null but it's not. So there's always the right record in the variable. I've tried also to set the Mode on Twoways but it's still not working.
How can I disable that the DataGrid loses the focus on the selected record?

Hopefully someone could help.

Comment: Going to need some clarifications. Your application is usable by multiple users at the same time? What do you mean by "User loses the focus"? Please give us some more XAML and your code-behind/viewModel.

Comment: Never heard of SQLNotification before... Try to set breakpoint to your `SelektierteZeile` setter - maybe its just flashed with null value / overidden with the same but new object (you know, old is thrown away, new is materialised becouse of notification)